# Oracle - error running stored procedure under proxy

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, proxy

I am using the Oracle XE database running in a Docker container. I have two stored procedures which I want to run under a proxy. One works okay, the other doesn't. Both scripts run fine under the username which created them.

Here are the two stored procedures (the former works, the latter doesn't)

```
-- @"/opt/oracle/oradata/Custom Scripts/orders_by_product_category_by_year.sql"
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE orders_by_product_category_by_year(p_cur OUT sys_refcursor) 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
AS 
BEGIN
    OPEN p_cur FOR
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orders.order_date) ASC) AS row_num, 
            product_categories.category_name, 
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orders.order_date) AS year,
            SUM(order_items.quantity*order_items.unit_price) AS value, 
            COUNT(1) AS count 
        FROM orders 
        LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.order_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.product_id = order_items.product_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.category_id = products.category_id 
        GROUP BY product_categories.category_name, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orders.order_date) 
        ORDER BY year ASC, product_categories.category_name;
END;
/

-- @"/opt/oracle/oradata/Custom Scripts/orders_for_year.sql"
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE orders_for_year(i_year IN NUMBER, o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
AS 
BEGIN 
    OPEN o_cursor FOR 
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orders.order_date) ASC) AS row_num, 
            orders.order_id, 
            customers.name AS customer_name, 
            CONCAT(CONCAT(employees.first_name, ' '), employees.last_name) AS salesrep_name, 
            orders.order_date, 
            (SELECT SUM(order_items.quantity*order_items.unit_price) FROM order_items WHERE order_items.order_id = orders.order_id) AS value 
        FROM orders 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN employees ON employees.employee_id = orders.salesman_id 
        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orders.order_date) = i_year;
END;
/
```

Here's the output from PL/SQL.

```
SQL> SHOW USER;
USER is "HR"
SQL> VAR cursor REFCURSOR;
SQL> EXEC ot.orders_by_product_category_by_year(:cursor);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC ot.orders_for_year(2016, :cursor);
BEGIN ot.orders_for_year(2016, :cursor); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "OT.ORDERS_FOR_YEAR", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1

SQL> SELECT * FROM user_tab_privs;
```

I can see no different in the privileges accorded each procedure.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM user_tab_privs;

GRANTEE    OWNER      TABLE_NAME                     GRANTOR    PRIVILEGE            GRA HIE COM TYPE       INH
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ---------- -------------------- --- --- --- ---------- ---
HR         OT         REGIONS                        OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         COUNTRIES                      OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         LOCATIONS                      OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         WAREHOUSES                     OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         EMPLOYEES                      OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         PRODUCT_CATEGORIES             OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         PRODUCTS                       OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         CUSTOMERS                      OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         CONTACTS                       OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         ORDERS                         OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         ORDER_ITEMS                    OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         INVENTORIES                    OT         SELECT               NO  NO  NO  TABLE      NO
HR         OT         ORDERS_BY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_BY_ OT         EXECUTE              NO  NO  NO  PROCEDURE  NO
                      YEAR

HR         OT         ORDERS_FOR_YEAR                OT         EXECUTE              NO  NO  NO  PROCEDURE  NO
PUBLIC     SYS        HR                             HR         INHERIT PRIVILEGES   NO  NO  NO  USER       NO

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Does the `HR` user have objects with the same names as the `OT` objects - particularly anything called `EMPLOYEES`? (Having the normal HR schema table with that name doesn't seem to cause this issue; but it might be a version-specific bug/issue - which version of XE are you using?)

Comment: Also, is 'proxy' relevant - that implies you get a different result if you're logged in directly as HR vs with proxy authentication; or did you just mean as a user other than the owner, OT?

Comment: @Alex Poole. Thanks for stepping in to help. OT is the DBA user, who creates and owns the procedures and tables. HR is a proxy off of OT that has EXECUTE and SELECT privileges. Ultimately this proxy will be used to run the procedures as ot[hr] from a cgi-bin script (CGI-BIN!. I know, right.). It's weird that one procedure runs under the HR proxy and the other doesn't. The only obvious (to me) difference is the IN parameter in the one that doesn't work. Both procedures work okay under the OT username that created them.

Comment: Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production                       0

Comment: So, here's what I know. Both stored procedures are owned by OT. HR can run one, but not the other. If I preface all the tables with the owner i.e. LEFT OUTER JOIN ot.employees rather than LEFT OUTER JOIN employees it works. But that begs a question, why does the other procedure work? Both procedures were created under the OT user. HR doesn't have rights to create stored procedures. It only has EXECUTE permission on the stored procedures and SELECT on the tables, and all those privileges were granted HR by OT.

Comment: Does HR have its own (non-proc) objects though? Particularly anything called `EMPLOYEES`?

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for sticking with it. I just now created a third stored procedure and HR was able to run it without my prefixing the table names with the owner schema OT. There's something about that one stored procedure. All the tables, not just employees, needs prefixed with the owner name.

Comment: SQL> SELECT object_name, owner, object_type FROM all_objects WHERE object_name = 'EMPLOYEES';

OBJECT_NAME          OWNER      OBJECT_TYPE
-------------------- ---------- -----------------------
EMPLOYEES            OT         TABLE

SQL>

Comment: Had a look through ALL_OBJECTS. There's only one employee table and that is owned by OT. HR does not own any objects, it just has SELECT and EXECUTE on objects owned by OT. There are no intersects between objects owned by OT and HR. Till tomorrow...

Comment: Solved. I was missing a SYNONYM for the employees table. Synonyms allow me to write queries which don't need to qualify table names with schema names. So, it's either create a synonym for the table or qualify its name with its schema. This is necessary to avoid ambiguity when referencing objects. I'm leaning toward qualifying names rather than using synonyms as the latter is itself ambiguous if you don't know/have forgotten you're using synonyms. Many thanks to Alex Poole.

Comment: Or `alter session set current_schema=ot`, which I prefer over synonyms *8-) Glad you figured it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The proxy user HR was missing a SYNONYM for the employees table. Synonyms facilitate writing queries which don't need to qualify table names with a schema name. So, it's either create a synonym for the table or qualify its name with its schema. This is necessary to avoid ambiguity when referencing objects. Having slept on it, I'm torn between qualifying names or using synonyms: the latter is ambiguous but flexible, the former rigid but unambiguous. But, anyway, problem solved.

```
OT> CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM hr.employees FOR ot.employees;

HR> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM employees;

  COUNT(1)
----------
       107

OT> DROP SYNONYM hr.employees;

HR> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM employees;
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

*Many thanks to Alex Poole.*